# Install a specific gem version with configuration options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install an old version of nokogiri, but I am having trouble specifying the format:

I'm using

```
gem install nokogiri -v 1.5.2 -- --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/lib
```

but this is not the correct syntax. Do you know how to do this?

**ERROR**

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/lib
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... no
-----
libiconv is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
```

Answer (score 1):

You’ve only specified the `lib` dir to use, try specifying the `include` dir as well:

```
gem install nokogiri -v 1.5.2 -- \
                 --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/lib \
                 --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/include
```

You may be able to specify both together:

```
gem install nokogiri -v 1.5.2 -- \
                 --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1
```

It looks like there was some [changes as to how Nokogiri finds `iconv` between versions 1.5.2 and 1.5.5](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/compare/v1.5.2...v1.5.5#diff-43), which may explain why you’re able to install the latest version but not 1.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

I simply installed homebrew, and used the `brew link inconv` to create the necessary symlinks to compile the gem.

```
$brew link libiconv
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1... 18 symlinks created
$gem install nokogiri -v 1.5.2
```